# When running report from forms (11g) get the error: REP-0788: Warning: The value of restricted LOV parameter is not among the selectable values

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

The parameter p_type is the LOV based on the select:

**Select p_type
 from parameter_types
 where table_name = 'X'
  and column_name = 'Y'
 UNION
 Select '-All-'
 from dual;**

Also the 
1)Restrict List to Predermined Values is checked and
2) Hide First Column is unchecked. 
3) initial value not given
I tried by setting up the into initial value to 'ALL'

Please help/suggest to debug this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you set parameter's initial value to something that LoV query doesn't return.

For example, suppose that you used Scott's `DEPT` table and set LoV to return this:

```
SQL> select dname from dept order by dname;

DNAME
--------------
ACCOUNTING
OPERATIONS
RESEARCH
SALES
```

Setting initial value to e.g. `FINANCIALS` would cause that error because `FINANCIALS` doesn't exist among selectable values (`ACCOUNTING`, `OPERATIONS`, `RESEARCH`, `SALES`).

What to do? Remove initial value, or set it to one of valid values.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your response, i tried my removing initial value and also i made  initial value as '-ALL-' which is in the select query that i used, no luck i still face same error. Any thing else i can try? please put your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. the datatype of the parameter was character but 0 was passed as the initial value which was a number.
**Solution:** I just resolved 0 in initial value. if it is mandatory for you then match it with the datatype. like in my case if it was mandatory then it can be written as '0'.